# Подключение к базе данных, и получение данных с сервера 1С в виде данных xml файла в android studio

Tags: android, 1с

Я новичок в android studio, столкнулся с такой проблемой в разработке мобильного приложения.

Попытаюсь понятно и кратко написать о  случившийся проблеме.

Как мне подключиться к базе данных 1С Предприятие на сервер, через android studio и получить данные товары магазина в xml формате?

Как через библиотеку "Retrfoit" подключиться к базе данных, и получить запрос на сервер к пользователю 1С?
Или лучше всего будет через библиотеку "okHttp"  подключиться?
Какие варианты ещё присутствуют?

Тем не менее  данные о товарах  магазина содержит форму (список-дерево в папках), Список-дерево тоже нужно реализовать в макет экрана приложения android studio

У самого присутствуют такие параметры:

1. Логин и пароль к базе 1С
2. Запрос
3. Порт
4. Ip-Адрес Сервера

Пример принципа получение/подключение к базе данных:

1. Создать запрос для подключения к серверу
   1.2 Запрос должен быть отправлен и получен  на сервер в 1С
   1.3 Получение данных из 1С для взаимодействия android studio(товары магазина)
   1.4 Данные который были получены из сервера, получить в xml файле и поместить в макет экрана приложения в виде папок (списка-дерева)

Переискал всю информацию в инете, так и не нашёл подходящий статьи(видеоуроков) который могли бы рассказать как решить данную задачку. Будьте так добры подскажите пожалуйста как и с чего начать?

Буду благодарен за любой и высказанный ответ.

Comment: Могу только подсказать по части 1С. Но, видимо, у вас больше вопросы по Android.

Comment: @Sagittarius Буду благодарен, даже если  вы подскажите по части 1С.

Comment: Какие данные вам о 1С предоставили, опишите более подробно. Не понял пункт 2 - "Запрос". Со стороны 1С будет HTTP- или WEB- service будет?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о мобильном приложении на Андроиде (а не о мобильном клиенте 1С), можно посоветовать следующее:

1. на стороне 1С, добавить в конфигурацию свой web-сервис, который будет отдавать данные по запросу GET, опубликовать базу в (Apache, IIS)
2. на стороне Андроид приложения, обращаемся http-GET к нашему web-сервису, полученные данные парсим